# How can I download an apk image into my android board (Permission denied error)

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to download my android apk image(APP like Camera/Music player) to android board like

```
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~/Project$ $ adb push app-debug.apk system/app
failed to copy 'app-debug.apk' to 'system/app/app-debug.apk': Permission denied
```

So to resolve this permission problem, I tried this:

```
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~$ adb shell
shell@s5p4418_navi_ref:/ $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: not found
```

Last I tried "adb root" on the following status:

```
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
0123456789abcdef    device
```

So the device is found. Now:

```
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~$ adb shell
error: device not found
andy@andy-VirtualBox:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

After "adb root", device not found any more.
How can I download an apk image into my android board?

Comment: By "android board" I assume you mean android device? You cannot su on an android device unless it is rooted. It is called "rooted" because you get acces to root. By "download my android apk image to android board" do you mean install an .apk on an android device?

Comment: Android apk means android application program(APP) like camera, music player etc..

Comment: I am not asking what apk stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Your device may not be rooted yet.

But you can install APK without root privilege:

`adb install <your_apk_file_path_here.apk>`

Comment: I want to download an apk image(in PC) into android board(device)

Comment: Do you want just copy apk from pc to android, or want to install it?